# Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Estou com uma regra de reescrita que achei em uma [pergunta muito antiga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/117978/2611951) do SO americano:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*/)([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ $1.php?%1 [L]
```

Esta regra faz com que eu possa passar um número qualquer de variáveis pelo URL sem ter que ficar fazendo uma regra pra cada quantidade:

```
 /mypage/param1/val1/param2/val2/param3/val3/...     --->
 /mypage.php?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3&...
```

Repare que o primeiro parâmetro passado vira o nome do arquivo php, os
 outros vão de dois em dois e viram parâmetro e valor de uma variável
 GET.

Eu quero que o primeiro parâmetro continue sendo o arquivo, mas que o segundo seja o valor de uma variável que sempre terá o mesmo nome:

```
/test/foo/bar/baz/u/e/...     --->
/test.php?varfixa=foo&bar=baz&u=e&...
```

Eu uso regex e até conseguiria fazer isso se fosse só regex, mas o `.htacces` tem algumas coisas diferentes.

Uma forma que pode me ajudar também seria sempre mandar para um `index.php`, mas com duas variáveis fixas:

```
/test/foo/bar/baz/u/e/...     --->
/index.php?varfixa1=test&varfixa2=foo&bar=baz&u=e&...
```

Comment: O que você espera quando há um número ímpar de parâmetros?

Comment: Provavelmente o pior que pode acontecer nesse caso é a última variável ficar vazia, então eu simplesmente ignoro ela, ou se ela for necessária eu exibo um erro na tela. A não ser que esse número ímpar seja 1, aí espero que vá para a página sem nenhum parâmetro no GET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Eu quero que o primeiro parâmetro continue sendo o arquivo, mas que o segundo seja o valor de uma variável que sempre terá o mesmo nome

```python
RewriteEngine on

#Quando há um número ímpar de parâmetros 
#    (eliminar "?$2" se quiser ignorar a última variável vazia)
RewriteRule ^((?:(?:[^/]+/){2})+)([^/]+)/?$ $1?$2    [QSA,L]

#Vira as duas últimas variáveis no ?parâmetro=valor
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/.*/)([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1?$2=$3  [QSA,L]

#Vira as duas primeiras variáveis no arquivo+".php?varfixa="+valor
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?varfixa=$2    [QSA,L]

#Caso que há um só parâmetro
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/*$ $1.php                      [QSA,L]
```

URL:

```
http://site.com.br/test/foo/bar/baz/u/e/v/f
```

Reescrita:

```
http://site.com.br/test.php?varfixa=foo&bar=baz&u=e&v=f
```

---

> Uma forma que pode me ajudar também seria sempre mandar para um `index.php`, mas com duas variáveis fixas

```python
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?:(?:[^/]+/){2})+)([^/]+)/?$ $1?$2                 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/.*/)([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1?$2=$3               [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?varfixa1=$1&varfixa2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/*$ index.php?varfixa=$1                     [QSA,L]
```

Pode testar aqui:
http://mariano.freevar.com/htaccess/test/foo/bar/baz/u/e/v/f

Comment: Perfeito! Exatamente isso! Sabe se tem alguma vantagem/desvantagem em usar o index.php para redirecionar para as outras páginas ou incluí-las ou se é só questão de gosto?

Comment: Acabei de reparar que não consigo enviar `/` para uma string. Quando tento usar `%2F` dá erro.

Comment: @Guilherme Não consigo forma de permitir-lhes. Nem mesmo com [flag B](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b).